# Having problems calling functions in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

This function should increase my snake size by increment width when I call in my `didbegincontact` function. However when contact is made it calls the function once and then never calls it again. I am not sure why when contact is made it does not keep increasing my snake size by increment

```
func increaseSnakeSize(increment: CGFloat){

    snake.snake1.size = CGSizeMake(snake.size.width + increment, snake.size.height + increment)
    snake.snake2.size = CGSizeMake(snake.size.width + increment, snake.size.height + increment)
    snake.snake3.size = CGSizeMake(snake.size.width + increment, snake.size.height + increment)
    print(snake.snake1.size)
}
```

// `didBeginContact`

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & physicsCategory.snakeCategory == 0b1) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & physicsCategory.foodCategory == 0b10 ){

    score++
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    food.removeFromParent()
    addFood()
    increaseSnakeSize(2)
}
```

Comment: can you explain your problem more clearly. `increaseSnakeSize` just call one and size increased or not? Next time it won't call?

Comment: Unless you sorted the first and second bodies (by categoryBitMask), you'll need to check if `firstBody` is the food and the `secondBody` is the snake.

Comment: Changing the size of a sprite doesn't change the size of its physics body. You will need to create a new, larger physics body each time the snake grows.

Comment: the snake1,snake2,snake3 are all 20x20 px at start. when contact is first made with food they are increased to 22x22 px. any contact made after the first one my snake blocks stay at 22x22 instead of incresing by 2 each contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the initial contact is made, the snake grows to 22x22, but its physics body's size stays at 20x20. A solution is to create a new physics body that's 22x22 for the initial contact, 24x24 for the next, 26x26 for the contact after that, ... For example,

```
func increaseSnakeSize (increment: CGFloat) {
    snake.snake1.size = CGSizeMake(snake.size.width + increment, snake.size.height + increment)
    // Create a new, larger physics body that matches the size of the snake
    snake.snake1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:snake.size.width/2.0)
    // Configure the physics body's property accordingly
    snake.snake1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ...
}
```

Another potential issue is the order of `contact.bodyA` and `contact.bodyB` can switch between contacts. You will need to check if the snake is the first body and the food is the second and the food is the first body *and* the snake is the second body. Here's an example

```
func didBeginContact (contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody, secondBody: SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.snakeCategory) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.foodCategory ) {
        // Increase size of the snake

    }
```

or

```
    let bitMask = contact.BodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.BodyB.categoryBitMask

    if bitMask == physicsCategory.snakeCategory |  physicsCategory.foodCategory {
        // Increase size of the snake
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not increase the `PhysicsBody` of your snake.  Do you have physics hit boxes showing in your app?  If not, I would recommend turning them on and seeing how it behaves.  In your View code, do:`self.showsPhysics = true`

Comment: i do not quite understand where you want me to add self.showPhysics = true

Comment: you should have some class that handles your SKView code,  in the init of that